# Specifying different database and related files location for a single PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql

We are reviewing how to segregate different PostgreSQL databases files to different drives on a single server with a single PostgreSQL instance. Does PostgreSQL allow this setup?

We can perform this function in both DB2 and MSSQL.

Does installing multiple PostgreSQL on the same server the only option to archive this setup? Installing multiple SQL instances on the same server method would add complexity and additional breakpoints for future maintenances and upgrades. I.e. we want to avoid.

Thanks in advance for any comments.
Sincerely,
Sunny

Comment: A bit unrelated: you don't need to `install` Postgres multiple times. you can create multiple _instances_ using different data directory (and TCP ports) using the same binaries. Just run `initdb` with a different data directory. But assigning a default tablespace to each database is probably a better (and easier) way.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into. Sunny

Answer (score 1):

the right way to do it would be:

```
t=# \! mkdir /pg/so
t=# create tablespace so location '/pg/so';
CREATE TABLESPACE
t=# create database so;
CREATE DATABASE
t=# alter database so set default_tablespace to so;
ALTER DATABASE
```

of course you can overcome `default_tablespace` if you have permissions to use other tablespace (which is seasily restricted)

Comment: Thank you! Will look into. Sunny